# Binding to ListView item tapped property from View Model

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind an event to a ListView, on my menu page, using the itemtapped property. Currently I am using MVVM (Xamarin form labs) framework in my app. What I am trying to accomplish is when a user taps the menu item the app navigates to the correct view.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
        ItemTapped= SET-BINDING-HERE >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          //setup template here
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

I want to bind the itemtapped event to this function:

```cs
public void NavigateTo(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
  {
      var test = args.Item as MenuModel;
      cPageTypes.GetByKey(test.CommandParameter)
                .SwitchRootPage(AIMCore.ViewModels.ElliottBaseViewModel.MasterPage);
      list.SelectedItem = null;
      AIMCore.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.MasterPage.IsPresented = false;
  }
```

I can currently get this to work if I add the function to the view's code behind and then set the **ItemTapped='NavigatTo**', but this seems wrong as it defeats the MVVM concept. What I really want to do is bind the event this same functionality in my ViewModel something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
        ItemTapped= "{Binding NavigateTo}" > // this binding is to the ViewModel
```

However this is not working or I am not doing it correctly. When I try implement it this way the code produces and error.

**Error:** 
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No Property of name ItemTapped found at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.BaseValueNode.SetPropertyValue

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've followed the same architecture and done through creating custom list control and created 1 bindable property with command which I've override in my View Model using below code:

Custom Control [.cs] page in my PCL

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace YourNS {

    public class ListView : Xamarin.Forms.ListView {

        public static BindableProperty ItemClickCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ListView, ICommand>(x => x.ItemClickCommand, null);


        public ListView() {
            this.ItemTapped += this.OnItemTapped;
        }


        public ICommand ItemClickCommand {
            get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty, value); }
        }


        private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item != null && this.ItemClickCommand != null && this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e)) {
                this.ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item);
                this.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML Page

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Samples.Views;assembly=Your Assebly Name">

<local:ListView ItemClickCommand="{Binding Select}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
```

And in my View Model [In this example, I've only opened dialog action sheet

```
private Command<Signature> selectCmd;
        public Command<Signature> Select {
            get {
                this.selectCmd = this.selectCmd ?? new Command<Signature>(s => 
                    this.dialogs.ActionSheet(new ActionSheetConfig()
                        .Add("View", () => {
                            if (!this.fileViewer.Open(s.FilePath))
                                this.dialogs.Alert(String.Format("Could not open file {0}", s.FileName));
                        })
                        .Add("Cancel")
                    )
                );
                return this.selectCmd;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution then what I have currently, and was considering developing something similar (trying to limit the number or renders for code sharing). I do have one more question, would adding the command parameter be the same as adding the item click command? I want to be able to pass the clicked item to the next view.

Comment: Sorry I know this is an old question but I'm getting the following error: 'Xamarin.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'ItemClickCommand' and no extension method 'ItemClickCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'Xamarin.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), any ideas why? I've got all the relevant references added but intellisense doesn't show the ItemClickCommand. Thanks.

Comment: @Thierry: are you using <ListView> or <local:ListView>? The ItemClickCommand is not defined on the built-in ListView that comes with Xamarin.Forms. The answer here has inherited from ListView to create its own custom ListView with a new property named ItemClickCommand. And to use it, you need to add the correct xmlns definition to the top of your XAML, and use <local:ListView> or <[whatever]:ListView>, where [whatever] is the xmlns you define.

Comment: Worked just fine for me on a PCL.

Comment: Don't forget CachingStrategy support. When you have the CachingStrategy property filled, you need to implement an extra constructor to prevent the ".....ctor' not found." Xamarin Exception. Add the following constructor to your custom ListView code. `public ListViewWithCommands(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy) : base(cachingStrategy)
        {
            ItemTapped += ListViewWithCommands_ItemTapped;
        }`

Comment: Additionally, when `this.ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item)`, the **e.item** must be used for the CanExecute call too. Thus use: `this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e.Item)` instead of `this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e)`

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can use an Attached Behavior

```
public static class ListViewAttachedBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached (
            "Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ListViewAttachedBehavior),
            null,
            propertyChanged:OnCommandChanged);

    static void OnCommandChanged (BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var entry = view as ListView;
        if (entry == null) 
            return;

        entry.ItemTapped += (sender, e) => 
            {
                var command = (newValue as ICommand);
                if(command == null)
                    return;

                if(command.CanExecute(e.Item))
                {
                    command.Execute(e.Item);
                }

            };
    }
}
```

Then call it on your ListView

```
 <ListView
        RowHeight="70"
        x:Name="AcquaintanceListView"
        b:ListViewAttachedBehavior.Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Acquaintances}">
```